# Duplicated cron jobs at same `scheduled_at` from different `created_at` times

Tags: cron, ee-1.12

What makes a cron job to be scheduled multiple times on the same `scheduled_at` time but by at different `created_at` times? See below. I'm having problems with repeated jobs never finishing.

[image]

Cron settings are as follow:

[image]

Comment: http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Schedule.php specifically: `trySchedule()` & http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php `_generateJobs()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not feel bad this is not your fault, I have the same thing on my machine and would hazard a guess that everyone does.

The problem is that the `Mage_Cron_Model_Observer::_processJob` never actually sets the job into the running mode, so next time the cron is called the it is just added again :(

The problem can be fixed by adding a line after the following comments:

```
/**
though running status is set in tryLockJob we must set it here because the object
was loaded with a pending status and will set it back to pending if we don't set it here
 */
$schedule->setStatus(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule::STATUS_RUNNING);
```

So it actually looks like Magento knew this was a problem but never actually fixed, which is odd. I have sent them a [patch](https://github.com/dmanners/MageCronFix/blob/master/cron-running-patch.diff) about this, but have heard nothing back, maybe I should bug them some more about that.

*Update*

Another possible fix, that is probably better, would be on the `Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule::tryLockJob` function and after you have a successful updated the entry in the database then also update the model itself. This would fix the whole thing and not just the observer :)

```
public function tryLockJob($oldStatus = self::STATUS_PENDING)
{
    if (
    $this->_getResource()->trySetJobStatusAtomic($this->getId(), self::STATUS_RUNNING, $oldStatus)
    ) {
        $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_RUNNING);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this also helped me in M2.2.2 CE